# Find list of directories of unreadable NTFS partition

Tags: ntfs, partition-recovery, directory-listing

I have a failing hard disk with two NTFS partitions:

- `C:` contains Windows (107 GB)
- `D:` which stores my data (393 GB partition)

I am using an Ubuntu live session as booting into Windows causes a BSOD; and I found out that `C:` is still mountable, but `D:` isn't.

Standard data recovery methods like `ddrescue` and `Clonezilla` can't really be used as I only have a spare 160gb external drive. Therefore I would like to just verify if there is a real need for recovery given a list of folders I have stored in the `D:` partition.

Since I can access the data stored on `C:`, is there any way for me to retrieve a list of folders on `D:`, such as via the cache of another application, or previously stored indexes?

Just a note that my personal folder `C:\Users\Sunxperous` cannot be accessed as there are folders/libraries in there symlinked(?) to ones in `D:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have since used [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover my files.

To answer the question, I chanced upon a file named `ntuser.dat` and associated ones in `C:\Users\Sunxperous` (readable in Terminal). There included data which contained strings of `D:` directories. However, not all directories (as far as I remember) were found in the files, so YMMV.